# How does youtube volume controls work internally?

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, html5-video, html5-audio

I'm curious how Youtube allows you to control the speaker volume through embedded controls in their website? Can Javascript control the speaker output? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Lots of multimedia sites have volume controls. Why do you think YouTube is doing anything special?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_volume.asp

Comment: Oh I just took YouTube as an example.

Comment: Anyway, as shown in the link, there's a standard `volume` property that can be used from JS.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the comment. I think that's the answer. Maybe if you post it as an answer I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the `volume` property of the `audio` or `video` element to set the output volume.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so yes, for `<video>` and `<audio>` elements JavaScript can control the volume of "playback".

That does not mean JavaScript in the browser is controlling your speakers, directly, it is more like your browser can send audio to your systems speakers... And your browser let's JavaScript signal certain intents, which are forwarded by your browser to the system and then to the speakers.

But if your speakers are set to a low volume, or are off, your JavaScript could not change that.

You can learn about the details on MDN here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video and here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Introduction